# Is it possible to use a custom port in app links?

Tags: android, android-app-links

I tried to add a port to my app links, but I can't get it to work.
Nothing is mentionned in the doc: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks

But at same time AndroidStudio autocomplete the `android:port` attribute and I also succeeded to validate my app links with this Google tool : https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator?hl=fr

```xml
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:host="my-domain.com" android:port="203" android:scheme="https" />
      </intent-filter>
```

Comment: What's the point of adding the port?  Do you want to handle mydomain.com:203 but not mydomain.com:80?

Comment: The point is to have multiple development environments, each dev environnement is listening on a different port

Comment: If you're building multiple apps with different ports, just use subdomains instead.  xxx.my-domain.com instead of my-domain.com

Comment: Well it's multiple dev environments, and not multiple app. I agree, I could use subdomains, but then I need to create DNS records from a  bash script, so instead I will probably just use some nginx on default ports as proxy with some path prefix to redirect to the final port

Comment: Why would you need to create DNS records?  These URIs don't actually send HTTP requests.  Which is part of why port doesn't really work-  there's no HTTP server reading requests on the Android device to actually intercept requests at different ports.  It's just matches domains and sends the intent to the proper recipient, no HTTP required.

Comment: You need DNS records because Google does verify if the domain authorize the app through the `/.well-known/assetlinks.json` file (https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks) but the request is done by Google servers and not the user device and the request is not done on each link but once in a while because the validation of app links is cached